# Is there a an option to modify the post content directly on the browser instead of having it reflected on browser by modifying in the database?

Tags: plugin-development

I am a newbie to the wordpress plugin development. I am trying to create a translate plugin that would translate a post on the browser (Not in the visual editor of wordpress).

For example, my plugin(which translates from X language to Y language) when installed should have a "Translate" button on the browser below every post(just like comment or like option). Upon clicking the Translate button, the post should be translated from X language to Y language on the browser itself, but the original post in the database shouldn't be modified.

I have learned about `get_post()` function to retrieve the post content. However, I have learned that I can retrieve the post and call my translation API to translate it, then save it to database. But, I want to know if there is any feature in wordpress plugin API that would just modify the content of the post on the browser itself.

If there's no such option, I would appreciate any suggestion to implement this.

Thank you.

Comment: After you retrieve the post and translate it, just echo it to the screen.

Comment: Thanks @johnh10. I am afraid that the page styles would be disturbed if I echo the post to the screen. I mean, I want to make sure as to how I can  replace the post content on the screen with updated content.

Comment: You intercept the post_content before it is displayed, translate it, and display the translated version.